# How to match value with comma in Sqlite Database with different column and return again with comma

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, sqlitemanager

I have database with three column like here

```
code      name           details
nd      new dear        sdadasd
dn      no dear         fdsfdsf
bs      bhai sahab      vdfgdfgdfg
```

Now I have value with comma like

> "nd, new dear"

How to match with different column in database and how to get same value from  database

> "nd, new dear"

Please suggest query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT code || ', ' || details AS val
FROM mytable 
WHERE code || ', ' || details = 'nd, new dear'
```

Comment: Thanks for comment Boris but i getting sql error : Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement] but for fetching from table i am using" ( code||',  '||name ) AS expr1 ".

Comment: now i want to match same value with comma from Database and return same with comma

Comment: And why are you using `code||', '||name`? It does not sound like MySQL syntax. Use `concat()` instead.

Comment: yes this is not belongs to mysql  i am using sqlite DB.